# Growth function of the class of all circles in the plane

Tags: combinatorics, machine-learning

I know that the VC dimension for this problem is 3. My concern is about the growth function. The following bound is obtained using the VC dimension:
$$m_{\mathcal{H}}(n)\le \sum_{k=0}^3\,{n\choose k}$$
When I simulate this hypothesis set up to $n= 10$, the maximum number of dichotomies I obtain is exactly $\sum_{k=0}^{3}\,{n\choose k}$. Is it by coincidence or is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Are you sure? I'd be surprised if you can arrange $10$ points in the plane such that for all subsets of $3$ of them there's a disc that contains only these three.

Comment: The total number of dichotomies is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{3}\,{n\choose k}$ does not mean that for all subsets of 3 of them there's a disc that contains only these three. There are dichotomies generated by disks enclosing $4,5, ... n$ points.